# SQL text with brackets tries to run a function

Tags: mysql, sql

Runnning the following SQL request pops up error about finding an invalid function

```
SELECT Name, Street FROM Persons
```

This is most likely because in the database are entries like Street(more)

How do I make sure these errors do not pop up?

Best Kurt

Comment: where is text with brackets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around terrible naming choices, use MySQL's identifier quoting (backtick), eg

```
SELECT `Name`, `Street` FROM `Persons`
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: I highly doubt this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incorrect:

What you meant to ask was:

```
SELECT Name(), Street FROM Persons
```

> Why does MySQL see `name()` as a function?

That's because the `()` brackets are how MySQL knows the difference between a field name and a function.
If you attach brackets to an identifier MySQL interprets it as a function. If that function does not exist it will give an error.
If you don't want that don't use the () in this context.

`()` are OK if you have a **space** in front of them:

```
SELECT name, (a+b) as aplusb FROM t1  <<-- OK
SELECT name FROM t1 WHERE (a = 1)     <<-- OK
SELECT name(a+b) FROM t1              <<-- Incorrect, tries to run a function named `name`
```

Comment: No that was not what I meant to ask:
In the DB there is a Street with the following name:

_ElmStreet(14)_

This is interpreted by SQL somehow as a function